# How do I print a string in raw format (including all the LINUX string denotes like \t and \n) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
"string1\tstring2\n\t\tstring3"
```

I want to print the string as it is in javascript. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSON.stringify()`

Example:

```
JSON.stringify(string1  string2     string3)

//console: string1\tstring2\t\tstring3
```